# How to add a character in a predefined string?

Tags: c++

I made a function that separates one of my data points to eliminate a character.I want to add R: G: B: into the 3 numbers. So for example if the values are 255,0,0 than it becomes

```
255
0
0
```

I want it to be

```
R:255
G:0
B:0
```

This is the function I made to separate the commas.

```
#include string
    void RGB(string input)
{
    istringstream ssString(input);

    while (getline(ssString, input, ','))
        cout<< input << endl;


}
```

Comment: Keep track of which line you're reading and append R, G or B accordingly. Also try and use `const string& input` in your signature, it helps avoid unnecessary copying.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @tadman I have tried to do that but since its in a while loop it just repeats those characters, so if I only had to do R: I would be fine but every iteration has to be different and I don't know how to implement that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just iterate through an array of your prefixes.  Something like this would be sufficient.

```
const char *prefix[3] = { "R:", "G:", "B:" };
for( int p = 0; p < 3 && getline(ssString, input, ','); p++ )
{
    cout << prefix[p] << input << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this without adding or subtracting lines from your code would be:

```
    int c = -1; // counter
    while(std::getline(ssString, input, ','))
        std::cout << (++c == 0 ? 'R' : c == 1 ? 'G' : 'B') << ": " << input << std::endl;
    return 0;
```

The ternary operator utilizes a counter variable that starts at -1, the ternary eliminates the need for several if statements. Note: you have to wrap the ternary in parenthesis `( )` otherwise the compiler throws errors at you.